# How to install spark on windows

Tags: sbt, apache-spark

I downloaded spark 1.0.2 and run on Cygwin

```
sbt/sbt assembly
```

but I got the error message:

```
Attempting to fetch sbt
You do not have curl or wget installed, please install sbt manually from http://www.scala-sbt.org/
```

But I already downloaded & installed sbt-0.13.5.msi from the given download-page. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sbt must use wget or curl to download additional dependencies, so you need to install these. On every single operating system other than windows these utilities usually come pre installed. Trying to get these to work on windows cygwin will be a pain, as with absalutely everything that isnt something to do with a monolithic GUI that costs a fortune.

I suggest if you wish to be at all productive in your future life you pick an operating system that works well for serious work. Windows only really works well for C# and MS office, serious computing? Big data? Hahahahaha, No!

Comment: So finally I used a VM for this.